# Can I have an Activity under a TabHost Without Being Part of that Those Tabs

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, android-tabhost

In other words, say I have a group of tabs Activity 1, 2, and 3 all with their own tabs, but Activity 2 links out to Activity 4 (who does not have its own tab), but I would still like the tabs to appear in the header of Activity 4 so the user can simple navigate back to where they were quite easily. Can someone help point me in the direction to accomplish this?

```
Intent createNote = new Intent(RecipeNotesActivity.this, CreateNoteActivity.class);
startActivity(createNote);
```

Comment: In what way do you want the user to go to Activity 4?

Comment: They will click a button from Activity 2 and go over to 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go for is [ActivityGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html) .
Make your Activity 2's Tab to host an ActivityGroup. From there, branch out to many activities as you need. Bear in mind that it would cost you more memory in case you are conscious about memory consumption.

I followed this [tutorial](http://gamma-point.com/content/android-how-have-multiple-activities-under-single-tab-tabactivity) to achieve. Good luck with your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible, use [Context.startActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) (Activity is a Context). Also check out the [Intent Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#ires) for explicit Intents.

Comment: Maybe i'm not understanding, but using Context.startActivity() gives me an error "Cannot make a static reference to a non static intent."

Comment: I think you try to start an activity in a static method.

Comment: How do I make my method static?

Comment: It just means use an object of that type.